# Transactional annotation is not working with Spanner database in springBoot java application

Tags: java, spring-boot, transactions, google-cloud-spanner

I am using the Spanner database in the springBoot project. I need to update or insert 2 tables in the same DB. I am using @Transactional with a function that is interacting with DB, also adding @Transactional to those functions which are called intermediately.

Also, I have added the below dependency in pom.xml
I am not using spring-cloud-gcp-starter-data-spanner as it's working properly.

```xml
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.27</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-cloud-spanner</artifactId>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-data-spanner</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

I have added
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
in spannerConfiguration file.

I am createing the bean also

```java
 @Bean
 @Autowired
 public SpannerTransactionManager spannerTransactionManager(SpannerProperties spannerProperties) throws Exception {
    DatabaseClient client = this.databaseClient(spannerProperties);
    return new SpannerTransactionManager(() -> client);
  }

functions

@Transactional
func A(){
    -- update table 1: func B()
    -- update table 2: func C(x)
}


@Transactional
func B(){
    -- Insert into Table 1
}


@Transactional
func C(int x){
    -- Read Table 1 history
    -- Get the total number of items
    -- if the number of items == x
        --update table 2: func D()
}

@Transactional
func D(){
    -- Update Table 2
}
```

This is my entire flow.

Test:
Just to check if the flow is atomic or not I changed the function D(), instaed of update I sent a request to insert another row with the same primary key.
Now the same table can't consist of 2 rows with a primary key so this insertion should not happen. As this entire flow is supposed to be atomic insertion table 1 also should roll back.
But in my case, it's not rolled back. Table 1 still has the insertion entry.

Please suggest how to make this flow atomic such that both table operations are executed in an atomic manner.

I tried @Transactional(Propagation = REQUIRED_NEW)
but got the error EnableTransactionManager doesn't have such a member. Spanner is not able to recognize this.

Comment: Could you include the code calling your functions?

Comment: fun A is being called by service layer.

Comment: from your code, it is not clear a/ how&when the function D is called b/ whether  the calling code in service layer has a @Transactional as well c/ is the calling code in service layer in within one method (one transactional boundary) or not.

Comment: A is in the service layer. A is getting called from the service layer. B is in another service.  I see transactional context is losing somewhere mid-way.

I moved the call to both the DB tables to a new service file. And made function in this service file Transactional. Other changes are as it is. This new service file contains the bean of both the service and now it's not losing context. Why it wasn't working earlier?